# How to programmatically change map color from day to night in ios7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, mapkit

I am working on an app for iOS 7, and am trying to change the map from day to night and night to day mode. I have not found any relevant APIs in iOS 7 documentation to do this.

Comment: Pretty sure this is an automatic thing. I'll be interested to see if anyone responds with a programmatic way of doing this.

Comment: I'm using UIMapKit in my app. I didn't see map changed it's mode automatically when I was testing it at night. Why do you thing it is an automatic thing?

Comment: Well in beta it was automatic. It seems apple may have removed this feature... http://forums.imore.com/ios-7/262271-just-me-there-no-night-mode-apple-maps-final-release-ios-7-a.html

Comment: @JohnRiselvato It only turns into night mode when in navigation mode.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a built in feature of `MKMapKit` so what you are asking is not possible without doing it yourself. If you were going to do it yourself, the best you could do would be to find a map tile source of 'night mode' tiles, and use the `MKTileOverlay` class (New to iOS 7) to replace the content of the map entirely.

A brief code example using the Open Street Map tile source (Not night tiles!)

```
// Put this in your -viewDidLoad method
NSString *template = @"http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
MKTileOverlay *overlay = [[MKTileOverlay alloc] initWithURLTemplate:template];

//This is the important bit, it tells your map to replace ALL the content, not just overlay the tiles.
overlay.canReplaceMapContent = YES;
[self.mapView addOverlay:overlay level:MKOverlayLevelAboveLabels];
```

Then implement the `mapView` delegate method below...

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKTileOverlay class]]) {
        return [[MKTileOverlayRenderer alloc] initWithTileOverlay:overlay];
    }
}
```

For full reference, see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKTileOverlay_class/Reference/Reference.html