# Give custom color to iOS Map view

Tags: ios, iphone, dictionary, apple-maps

I need to implement following color to our iOS Map.

[image]

Can any have suggestion,how to make this in iOS.

Thank in advance.

Comment: did u try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996478/how-to-programmatically-change-map-color-from-day-to-night-in-ios7

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13592117)

> Don't think you can change the imagery before it is rendered to the screen. However, you can use an MKOverlayView over the entire world that achieves the same effect.